# installing CDAT for Python

Tags: python, installation

I'm running on a Mac, and I'm trying to get CDAT downloaded to use with Python (and the Anaconda package I have downloaded). I try following along with online sources to set it up, but nothing seems to really help. Can anyone offer any assistance?

I successfully downloaded CDAT_lite and can use to with Python/Anaconda, but the with it is that when I try importing modules cdms2 and regrid2, I got an error message stating that the "image not found"

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cdat_lite-6.0rc2-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/cdtime.so, 2): Library not loaded: libnetcdf.7.dylib 

Referenced from: /Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cdat_lite-6.0rc2-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/cdtime.so

Reason: image not found
```

Any help is much appreciated! I'm completely lost and have no idea how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is trouble loading the netCDF libraries.

You need to have the latest release of UV-CDAT (which includes the CDAT libraries).  Instructions on how to install them are here: https://github.com/UV-CDAT/uvcdat/wiki/Installation-on-Mac.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Yes; unfortunately since I'm new to StackOverflow, I'm not able to comment on the author's post yet.  The question as posed is difficult to answer since a lot of key information is missing, e.g., what steps did the author already take to try to install the software?  What version of Mac OS are they running?  etc.

Comment: "and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post." - one more reason not to argue with atomatically posted comments...

Answer (score 0):

Hi this seems to be a rather old version. Please try using our latest version at: http://uvcdat.llnl.gov
Install instructions are at: http://uvcdat.llnl.gov/installing.html

You can either build from source: https://github.com/UV-CDAT/uvcdat/wiki/Build
or simply download the binaries: https://github.com/UV-CDAT/uvcdat/wiki/install
Make sure to read the pre-requisites page first ;)
https://github.com/UV-CDAT/uvcdat/wiki/System-Requirements